# Мазурик - что означает?

Tags: значение-слов

Это ругательное слово? В детстве называли нас маленькими.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

МАЗУРИК, -а; м. Нар.-разг. Вор, мошенник, хулиган. Какие-то мазурики сорвали цветы. Растёт мазуриком. Мазурики забрались в огород.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

А вот из словаря Даля.

новг. мазурник, мазурин *(от мазур. поляк или от мозуля, замарашка, оборванец?),* **карманный вор, комнатный и уличный в городах, особ. в столицах, где они придумали свой язык, байковый или музыку.** Ходишь по музыке? говоришь ли по-нашему? Фараон, будочник; бутырь, городовой; фага, лазутчик; клюй, пристав; михлютка, жандарм; стрела, казак; аршин, купец; мешок, приемщик краденого; уборка, похороны; саро, бабки, деньги; шишка, бумажник; шмель, кошелек, теплухо, шуба; голуби, белье на чердаке; скамейка, лошадь; лоханка, табакерка; веснухи и стуканцы, часы; камбала, лорнет; лепень, платок; сережка, замок; стриканцы, ножницы; жулики, нож, и мальчишка помощник; выночить, срубить, вынуть из кармана и пр. -ков, ему принадлежащ. -ричий, к ним относящ. Мазурить, мазурничать, промышлять карманным воровством особ. в столицах, на ярмарках и на торгах. Мазурка ж. народная пляска мазуров, мазовецких поляков, и напев к ней; она переиначена и принята в число общественных плясок. Мазурный, -рочный, к этой пляске или музыке относящ. Мазурист м. -тка ж. искусный плясун мазурки или охотник до нее.

Answer (score 1):

> Происходит от мазура «неряха», от мазать, далее от праслав. *mazati,
>   от кот. в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. мазати, мажѫ (др.-греч.
>   ἀλείφω, χρίω, λιπαίνω), русск. мазать, укр. ма́зати, ма́жу, белор.
>   ма́заць, болг. ма́жа, сербохорв. ма̏зати, ма̏же̑м, словенск. mázati,
>   mа̑žеm, чешск. mazat, словацк. mаzаť, польск. mazać, mażę, в.-луж.
>   mazać, н.-луж. mazaś. Родственно латышск. (iz)muôzêt «мучить,
>   перехитрить» (из «намазать»), muôzêt «есть много, жадно; дурачить,
>   колотить», лит. mė́žti «унавоживать», латышск. mêzt «чистить навоз,
>   мести», греч. μάσσω (μεμαγμένος) «давлю, мешу, мажу», μαγεύς «пекарь»,
>   μαγίς «месиво, тесто», μᾶζα «тесто», др.-в.-нем. mahho^n «соmроnеrе,
>   jungere, instituere», нов.-в.-нем. mасhеn «делать», арм. mасаnim
>   «густею»

(Фасмер)

Вот в этом значении, "неряха", "мурзилка", скорее всего и называли вас в детстве. "Взрослое" значение "плут", "мошенник" скорее всего вторично ибо в нем не прослеживается общеславянской этимологии. Появление его в русском объясняется скорее всего влиянием польского арго. Вряд ли ваши родители или взрослые родственники видели в вас мошенников.